# Switch slider (using a checkbox) is flickering with AJAX "back" history

Tags: javascript, ajax, pushstate, html5-history, htmx

The following code queries a `state.json` file on load and updates the slider switch. It uses `fetch(...)`. It works.

When clicking on the text "Click on this text...", the top `div` is replaced by another text with HTMX.

**Problem**: when clicking browser "Back" button, **the switch slider moves again (flickering)**, and it should not: only the div `#me` should be modified by HTMX, not the rest.

**Question: how to avoid the switch to flicker when doing history Back?** (even if we remove the CSS transition, we still have a very fast flickering).

Live demo [here](http://5.135.181.77/test-Uls9z2gryn9h/Gqy341uccmn7/).

`index.php`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.8.0"></script>
<style>
.switch { appearance: none; height: 30px; width: 52px; background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 22px, dodgerBlue 22px), linear-gradient(to right, white 0 22px, dodgerBlue 22px 60px); background-position: 4px 4px; }
.switch { transition: 0.2s; }
.switch:checked { background-position: 26px 4px; }
</style>
<div hx-get="page2.txt" hx-push-url="true" id="me">Click on this text to go to next page</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="switch">
<script>
fetch("state.json").then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
    document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = data['state'] == 'checked';
});
</script>
```

`page2.txt`

```
Hello, now click on the "Back" history button of your browser.
```

`state.json`

```
{"state": "checked"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, it seems that using [`hx-history-elt`](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-history-elt) on the `div` containing the text, but not the slider switch, solves the problem.